# Android: RTSP Audio Stream issue

Tags: android, audio, stream, rtsp

I'm trying to play a RTSP Radio Stream in my Android Application.

I actually have this code:

```
btnStart = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(/* RTSP URL */);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("MediaPlayer", ex);
        }
    }
});
```

But I also have some issues:

```
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (701, 0)

    [ 08-17 19:39:16.109   223:  529 D/ ]
    RPCSendMsgToClient: remote_app_id = 4, context_id = 536871936

    [ 08-17 19:39:16.109   148:  276 D/ ]
    AppRecvFromRPCIFTask: recieved_bytes = 22

    [ 08-17 19:39:16.109   148:  276 D/ ]
    IPC ReadCB:  RET idx(1249) 

E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
W/MediaPlayer: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
    at com.oseas.lavozdeloeste.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:28)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The RTSP Stream is only audio without video. Any help?

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to implement Streaming Media Player. Here is an [Example](https://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/). Hope it will help you and also Which audio format is comming in RTSP. Check the audio format. [Android Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Answer (score 0):

u have used

```
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

u should use

```
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
```

instead of

```
mediaPlayer.prepare()
```

and thats it.. it should work then